# How to find parent records with only 1 child record

Tags: soql, community, reporting, dynamic-soql

I want to pull all the parent records which have only 1 child record either using a query or report or any other way. For example all the accounts with only 1 contact record. I don't want to create  roll-up summary field.

Comment: You can use SOQL query with Group by and Having clause

Answer (score 7):

> Query on Contact using Aggregate function `Count()`

```
SELECT AccountId, count(Id)
FROM Contact
GROUP BY AccountId
HAVING count(Id) = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I want to filter the results with more conditions like country code and is Primary(roll up summary field) but i am not able to do it due to below error:"field 'Is_Primary__c' can not be grouped in a query call". My query "SELECT AccountId,Account.Country_vod__r.Name,Count(id) FROM Contact group by Accountid,Account.Country_vod__r.Name,Account.Is_Primary__c having count(id)=1 and Account.Country_vod__r.Name='CA' and Account.Is_Primary__c=0

Answer (score 2):

Hi @sam you can do it in reports also with out creating a Roll-up-summary field.For this you need to create a report with accounts & contacts.

1.For this report you need to use Cross filter like **Acccounts with contacts**

2.You need to change to summary report with grouping as **Account name**.

3.You need to create a formula based on **RowCount**.

For reference:

[image]

You can do it in either query also as ishwar answer.using count with aggregate list.

I hope it solves your problem

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. But this report will pull accounts with more than 1 contact so it will not work in my case. Please let me know if there are any other ways to achieve it. Thanks.

Comment: Ya but you cant filter the formula but if you can display in ascending order based on formula field. @sam

Comment: Ya but i cannot do it because i have more that 76K records.